# How does this lambda function put a comma at thousands

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Eg:317615384.61538464 -> 317,615,384.61538464

```
def answer_thirteen():
   Top15 = answer_one()
   Top15['PopEst'] = Top15['Energy Supply'] / Top15['Energy Supply per Capita']

   Top15['PopEst'] = Top15['PopEst'].apply(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x)) #how does this work

   return Top15['PopEst']
```

Answer (score 1):

That lambda uses the [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) builtin method on the string "{:,}", passing in the argument `x`. This string contains a format specifier (in fact, that's all it contains), which is what tells the format method how to display `x`. You can read more about format specifiers in Python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). From that page:

> The ',' option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator.